# Help with Japanese for a tattoo - I swear there’s a good reason!

Tags: kanji

If anyone could help me make sure I don’t make a stupid white girl mistake and get the wrong thing tattooed on me that would be very appreciated!

I had two cats who died very recently and I’d like to get a tatto in their memory. I named them Tsuki and Yuki when I was 7 years old, and I would love to be able to have a tattoo of their names in Japanese kanji, along with 2 cat silhouettes.

From looking on the internet I have found 雪 for Yuki, as I do remember choosing it with the intention of it meaning ‘snow’.
And I have found 月 for Tsuki as again I remember choosing it with the intention of it meaning “moon/lunar”

If anyone could help me out I would honestly be so so so grateful, these cats meant a lot to me.

Answer (score 4):

You are not making a mistake as both Kanji are correct:  雪 Snow and 月 Moon.  In the future if you want to verify a character I would recommend using jisho to look it up: https://jisho.org/

Good luck!